# Bind incoming JSON to models when DataMember names differ from property names

Tags: json, .net, binding, webapi

I have this model class, which is automatically populated by sending a POST request to a .NET 4.5 Web API Controller.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name="Message")]

public class Message {
    
    [DataMember(Name="text")]
    public string text {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public Guid id {get; set;}

}
```

Now, when I send a request like this to the controller, I am able to work with a automatically-bound model:

```
POST /messages/
text=foo&id=1
```

Unfortunately this only works because the DataMember Names are the same as the property names, only lowercase.

However, what if my DataMember Names and the property names differ, such as:

```
[DataMember(Name="content")]
public string text { get; set; }

POST /messages/
content=foo&id=1
```

would then result in a binding error, as the "content" field can not bound to Message.text

The DataMember attribute is ignored, for whatever reason - it will be used if in serialization, in deserialization it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending JSON

this is a traditional post with form fields

```
POST /messages/
text=foo&id=1
```

A JSON will be

```
{"text":"foo","id":1}
```

I'm sure this is not a response about what you are looking for, but I think is important you understand you aren't sending JSON

Comment: Thanks, I'm sending actual JSON in the app - it doesn't make a difference though. The problem that [DataMember] names are ignored persists.